# javafx 2 javascript api - getting the java controller

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-2, fxml

I have a FXML file that has lots of controller methods that I send to a normal Controller. However, I have been recently adding several small handlers that do very trivial things and was wondering if I could do them in javascript in the FXML file itself instead. However, I seem to have come across an issue: I cannot find a documented way to get the controller object in javascript. How can I get the controller object in javascript? (and no, I can't use static methods because I have lots of these controllers on lots of objects)

Current Code using Java:
FXML file:

```
...
<GridPane fx:id="moveOverlay" onMouseClicked="#mouseOverlayClicked" ...>
....
```

and the java controller:

```
...
@FXML
private void mouseOverlayClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getClickCount() > 1)
    {
        this.enableNestedEditing();
    }
    else if (e.isControlDown())
    {
        this.selectSelf();
    }
}
...
```

Desired FXML:

```
...
<fx:script>
var controller = [what goes here?];

function mouseOverlayClicked(e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {
        controller.enableNestedEditing();
    else if (e.isControlDown()) {
        controller.selectSelf();
}
</fx:script>
...
<GridPane fx:id="moveOverlay" onMouseClicked="mouseOverlayClicked" ...>
...
```

and no corresponding Event Handler in the java class (aside from the other methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough, `controller` is already defined in the javascript part of fxml. So `var controller =` is not necessary.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?language javascript?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="fxmltest.SomeController">
    <fx:script>
        function buttonClicked() {
          controller.print("hallo");
        }
    </fx:script>
    <children>
        <Button text="John Doe" onAction="buttonClicked()"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Controller:

```
package fxmltest;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class SomeController {

  @FXML
  public void print(String s){
    System.out.println("from javascript: "+s);
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If it is, I couldn't find it. I discovered this by trial&error.